# Combine xAxis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart from `highcharts.js` my problem is that for example... I have a line chart with 5 values (5 points) and my chart shows the xAxis like this `from value 1 to value 2: 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1`, what I want to do is to remove `0.25, 0.5, 0.75` and keep only 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, etc... something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Here is a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbRoJv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control that with tickInterval:

```
    xAxis: {

        labels: {
            rotation: -33,
        },
      tickInterval:1
    },
```

http://codepen.io/bhlaird/pen/WoGmNd

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Comment: Excellent! Works fine now! another question... what should I do to display text for example instead of a number, for example with an interval of 1 but shows "Result 1", "Result 2", etc. instead of numbers?

Comment: You can either use categories http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories or if the lables you want are always a combination of a word and the number, you could use the formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter